# How to update data through a DataGridView in VS 2015

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I just need to update data through a dataGridView by clicking a cell and just typing something new there. I thought it would work if I assign parameters with actual row cell but failed. How do I go about that?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            textBox1.Tag = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["surname"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["country"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["countrycode"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["prefix"].Value.ToString();
            row.Cells["number"].Value.ToString();
}

private void uPDATEToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = DESKTOP-9I0BNAS\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = CAVID; Integrated Security = True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contacts SET name=@name,surname=@surname,country=@country,countrycode=@countrycode,prefix=@prefix,number=@number Where ID = @id ", con);

            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Tag);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countrycode", row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefix", row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
}
```

Comment: any error when running the uPDATEToolStripMenuItem_Click?

Comment: No. says 'succes' but nothing is really updated when you check out table

Comment: What is the datatype of your Id column ... not shure if it's a good idea to use AddWithValue with an object property (textBox1.Tag) ... maybe you should cast/convert to int if that's the column type ...